# Link more than one file to executable

Tags: c++, testing, cmake, ctest

How can I link more than one file(test) to an executable?

I have this code:

```
set(TEST_EXE_NAME Test)
add_executable(${TEST_EXE_NAME} t1.cc)
add_executable(${TEST_EXE_NAME} t2.cc)
add_test(Test ${TEST_EXE_NAME})
```

This of course doesn't compile and I understand why. But is there a way to put both tests into one executable?

Comment: I do this with command line arguments and combining the result to an overall result. That along with logging helps me identify the reason(s) for failure.

Comment: @drescherjm I'll try that! do you know if there's a way to do it without that?

Comment: `add_test` can parse your output using `PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION` or `FAIL_REGULAR_EXPRESSION`. That's more flexible but probably not what you wanted.

Comment: @usr1234567 Thanks! Edited my question for an alternative I'd prefer.

Comment: Can you please give more details why you are trying to do this? Just a guess from my side: you want to have a "test runner" and I'm wondering if you know about [tag:ctest] coming with [tag:cmake]? It will run everything you have given with `add_test()`. So the simplest solution would be to build the two executables with different names and add both as tests.

Comment: @Florian thanks! I reset TEST_EXE_NAME after the first test. If you want to post this as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just repeat it.

```
set(TEST_EXE_NAME Test)
add_executable(${TEST_EXE_NAME} t1.cc)
add_test(Test ${TEST_EXE_NAME})
set(TEST_EXE_NAME Test1)
add_executable(${TEST_EXE_NAME} t2.cc)
add_test(Test1 ${TEST_EXE_NAME})
```

Since you're testing this way the names can be more descriptive for each executable anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can give multiple source file names to the `add_executable` command:

```
add_executable(${TEST_EXE_NAME} t1.cc t2.cc)
```

Comment: I get the error that there are multiple definitions of main.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question. If you want to link multiple files into one executable, then my answer is for you. If you have multiple files that each must be linked into their own executable, follow the reply by anc.